# unable to read text from downloaded pdf file c#

Tags: c#, pdf, download

I have downloaded a pdf file using this command
var res = GetStringSync(remoteUri);
res gets data in binary format. How can I convert this to string or stream so that I can read this text. I used different pdf extraction libraries but they generate exception.
How can we download a pdf file using HttpClient and ReadAsStreamAsync methods.

Comment: I don't think you can read data from pdf directly, you need to use some library to extract the text out of it. tesseract-ocr might help you

Comment: I tried two pdf extraction libraries uglytoad and bitmiracle but both are throwing exceptions about the data in the string res.

Comment: I searched for uglytoad does this code help? https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/discussions/370#discussioncomment-1357904

Comment: *"GetStringSync(remoteUri); res gets data in binary format"* - what do you mean by "binary format"? The method name is more a hint that it retrieves a `string` which is exactly _not_ binary. Or does the string contain a textual encoding of binary data, e.g. using base64, uue, or hex format? In that case you obviously have to decode the encoded binary before using it.

Comment: e∟???e??1F?↑↓?g,?2:?H??M??3$????n??2<????X?d,D2j?G?s???*?7??????<??iZ?l?☺▲wl=♠v;v?+∟?♠☺?????☺S|???⌂☺???. I get data in this format. I don't know which format is this. What function will I use to decode this so that I can read text from pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following NuGet packages to read your PDF:

tesseract-ocr ([tesseract-ocr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/)) suggested by @Kartoos
PdfPig ([PdfPig](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfPig/0.1.6-alpha-20220220-b0a5f)) suggested by @Kartoos

Here is a code sample for PdfPig:

```
// Be sure to declare all your **using** clauses prior to this.
// such as **UglyToad.PdfPig**. Also be sure to add your references.

//var stream = {Get Memory stream here}
    
var sb = new StringBuilder()
using PdfDocument pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Open(stream);
    
// Iterate to extract document pages
foreach (var page in pdfDocument.GetPages())
{
   sb.AppendLine(page.Text);
}

// Your Pdf text for all your pages is here
var text = sb.ToString();
```